# How to pass arguments in system() command?

Tags: perl

I have a abc.pl  perl script and from this script i am using a system() command to execute another xyz.pl perl script. Now i want to pass some arguments from system() command to use it in xyz.pl scipt
i am using below piece of code but i could not able to get the arguments properly.

```
abc.pl
=======
{
   my @cmd = "xyz.pl" . "arg1" . "arg2";
   system($cmd)
}

xyz.pl
======
{
  my @arg1 = shift(@ARGV);
  my @arg2 = shift(@ARGV);
}
```

Can you please suggest me solution?

Comment: the obvious answer to the question is "_very carefully!_"

Comment: You're not putting any spaces between the arguments.

Comment: Also, you're assigning a string to a list variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), just pass it a list:

```
system PROGRAM LIST
```

Therefore for your script it would be the following:

```
# abc.pl

my @cmd = ("xyz.pl", "arg1", "arg2");
system(@cmd)
```